# How to send a number from a form in C# to a console program in C++

Tags: c#, c++

I need to run an unmanaged C++ application, this application must be connected to a library in C# (dll which when loading must show a form with a button) and wait for form close event to terminate.

While the form is loaded, at the moment of pressing the button the click event should be executed, which should execute a function that can send a number of return to the console application in C ++ and this application will show the resulting number in the output of the console.

What I need is to solve point 5. shown below, I read a lot of documents but almost all refer to the interoperation between a C++ dll and a C# application and not the reverse (Return an integer value from C# dll to a C++ console application) is what is needed here.

The execution must be dynamic, that is, while the form is displayed, a communication should be established from a function of the C# library and a function of the parent C++ console application.

All the examples that I have been able to find do almost the same, load the libraries, establish the communication and, from the C++ console application they call a function of the C# library and show the resulting return value and the application ends, but no example shows how to load the C# library, show the form, press a button, and send a integer number as a result to the C++ parent console application and show the result in the output of the console.

If you have any idea how to implement the Callback, I would be very grateful.

What I have tried:

What has been achieved is:

1. Load C++ console application (unmanaged), achieved
2. Load a C# library from the C++ console application, achieved
3. Import and communicate with some functions exported from the C# library, achieved
4. When loading the C# library, from this library a form with an button is shown, achieved
5. While the form is displayed, press the button and execute a function in C# that returns an integer to the C++ console application and print the result in the output of the console from the C++ console application, pending

Comment: Use an interprocess communication library. Either in memory, or network.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, it is not possible to use more tools than those already proposed. If you have any link to an example of memory use it would be perfect

Comment: Open a socket in C++, connect to it in C#, that should be enough. If you can use network.

Comment: For now everything is in the same physical location, there is no need for different repositories

Comment: If you can't use a network lib, an IPC lib or the crappy file way, then you can't do what you want.

Comment: An example that I have seen is the use of the public void CallBack {} function in the C++ application and using Marshalling from C #, but the proposal was incomplete and impossible to prove

Comment: And it uses either IPC or network communication.

Comment: You have to use inter process communication. You could use COM, or you could create a socket yourself, as other people have mentioned. Both would required at least 10 pages articles to cover and won't fit in an answer box or comment here. Google "C++ to C# COM" or "Tcp Socket for <language X>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One proposition: When your app C# want to send a value, it writes it in a file in folder `C:\Temps\token.txt`.

Then, if your application C++ detects a file named `token.txt` (by a loop for each 10s for example) in `C:\Temps`, it reads it and gets the value

Comment: @Antoine V, I have seen that kind of technique but for security reasons it is not possible to be used

Comment: @Fisad it's up to you, this is a proposition that was used in one of my project :)

Comment: @AntoineV I understand it works, but it's a very crappy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solution not related to network or interprocess communications at least

- call unmanaged callback or delegate from managed code (see "[How to: Marshal Callbacks and Delegates By Using C++ Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-marshal-callbacks-and-delegates-by-using-cpp-interop)")
- use [an event object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/using-event-objects) to signal pressed button and a [named shared memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) to pass a value back

Please note that implementing complex things to doing simple ones is the characteristic of not well designed application.

Comment: Fantastic but, what is needed is to implement it between C ++ and C # and not between C ++ and C ++

Comment: I see, the Microsoft's example is for marshaling between unmanaged and managed code. You may write unmanaged code in C#, too.

Comment: You may write **managed** code in C#, too. Sorry, my mistype.